# errors in generated file of databinding

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

i trying to implement databinding in project

it works/run without error

but then i checked ActivityMainBindingImpl(auto generated) of activity_main

i see those errors in those file

[image]

> what i did so far is:-----

invalidate caches and restart <-- this doesnt helped

clean and rebuild <-- didnt worked

### why is it generating the errors

Comment: Do not worry about what's inside `build` folder. This is generated and as you said it works fine.

Comment: @Sylwek but i could see the red line below  `app` folder ...which is quiet frustrating...